# Woocommerce | Wordpress - Show VAT to price (e.g : £495+vat)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Having problems with Wordpress's Woocommerce.

+VAT does not show on product page. It says £495.00 but it should say £495.00+vat

I've also taken a screenshots of the front and back end of how it looks.

[front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ0de.png)

[back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwh6.png)

Please can someone advise and assist here. Would it be simply that I need to tick or un-tick something or add a plugin, or do I have to add a piece of code on the page?

Please advise.

Comment: FIXED!

Just added '+VAT' to Specify extended price data in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to filter WooCommerce's price displaying function. In your instance, try sticking this in your theme's function.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'vat_price_html', 100, 2 );
function vat_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    return $price.'+VAT';
}
```

This is going to be the easiest way to do it unless you want to modify all of your template files.

Comment: This would work, but there's also an admin setting that will work without needing any code.